# 2D Cel-Shading in JavaFX

Tags: graphics, javafx

I am writing a pretty simple 2D game in JavaFX, and although its only in preview release at the moment, I am looking to try to implement (even basically) some sort of Cel-Shading onto my game objects.

Does anyone know if there are reference implementations of cel-shading out there that I could use, or perhaps, some advice for me in this field?

I guess it doesnt have to be JavaFX specific, but that would help.

I don't have much experience with graphics programming, however, I'm an experienced java/c# programmer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, 2D and cel-shading are antonymous... [Cel-shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel-shaded_animation) is a 3D technique to look 2D, so this technique has no place in 2D graphics.

If I am wrong or if you meant something else, just yell! :-)

Comment: You are right :) I guess I was just after that effect that cell-shading gives, a real toony effect

Comment: Yes, I understand. It might be interesting to have a Lighting effect with a cell-shading rendering (after all Lighting is pseudo-3D) but it belongs to JavaFX implementation more than JavaFX coding.